# Sequelize - Associate a model that is associated with another model

Tags: node.js, api, sequelize.js

I'm tottaly new in NodeJS + Sequelize.
I have a question about association.

I have 3 models :

- ModelA
- ModelB
- ModelC

I have two association :

```
ModelA.belongsTo(ModelB, {as: 'myModelB'});
ModelB.belongsTo(ModelC, {as: 'myModelC'});
```

Now, i get the `ModelA`:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
ModelA.findAll({ include: [ 'myModelB' ]})
    .then(result => {
        res.json(result);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

In the response i only have the info of the `modelB`but the `ModelB`does not have the info of `ModelC`

My result :

```
{
  id: 1,
  attr1: 'toto',
  attr2: 'tata',
  myModelB: {
               attrB1: 'Hello',
               attrB2: 'World',
               fk_modelC: 1
            }
}
```

The result i want :

```
{
  attr1: 'toto',
  attr2: 'tata',
  myModelB: {
               attrB1: 'Hello',
               attrB2: 'World',
               fk_modelC: {
                           attrC1: 'It',
                           attrC2: 'Works!'
                          }
            }
}
```

How can i include the `ModelC` in the `ModelB` when i use the `ModelA`?

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is: https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/models-usage/index.html#nested-eager-loading

Perhaps something like:

```
ModelA.findAll({ 
    include: [{
      model: ModelB, 
      as: 'myModelB', 
      include: [{
         model: ModelC,
         as: 'myModelC', 
      }]
   }]
 })
    .then(result => {
        res.json(result);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Comment: You are missing as in the include, you have to mention the name of the association in the include otherwise it will throw an error of Sequelize Eager Loading error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snipet:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    ModelA.findAll({
        include: {
            'myModelB',
            include: {
                'myModelC'
     }
        }
    })
        .then(result => {
            res.json(result);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```